# Refreshing a web page if we have SessionID

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

Normally a web page get refreshed if `browser` send it back to `server`. Have we any trick to Refresh a web page if we have `SessionID` only by `server`.

Answer (score 1):

No. `HTTP` is a **request-response protocol**, it is not a server-push... (until **websocket** are here) Server just serves the request, and *the request is initiated at client.*

Comment: have you any `websocket` example in `C#`?

Comment: It is funny I am just watching a talk on it here http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM14